# How can I adjust the offset in my query using extract(dow from date) so that Monday is 0 - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, dayofweek

Im using Postgres, and I would like to get the days of week number as follow:

```
(Monday: 0, Tuesday: 1 ,... Sunday:6)
```

But using following SQL in Postgres function

```
extract(dow from current_date)
```

Postgres gives me following back:

```
(Sunday: 0, Monday: 1 ,... Saturday:6)
```

How can I adjust the offset in my query using extract(dow from date) so that Monday is 0 and not Sunday?

And I wonder why does the following Postgres function:

```
date_trunc('week',(current_date)
```

Uses a logic different from extract dow.

```
(Monday: 0 -> Week Start, Tuesday: 1 ,... Sunday:6 -> Week End)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isodow` instead of `dow`

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

> `isodow`
>         The day of the week as Monday (1) to Sunday (7)

Then simply subtract 1 from the result:

```
extract(isodow from current_date) - 1
```